# Normalizing a field using a single UPDATE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, replace, normalization, canonicalization

Is there any way to perform an update for normalizing a field using a single query?

Example:

```
UPDATE person SET name = REPLACE(name, 'á', 'a');
UPDATE person SET name = REPLACE(name, 'é', 'e');
UPDATE person SET name = REPLACE(name, 'í', 'i');
UPDATE person SET name = REPLACE(name, 'ó', 'o');
UPDATE person SET name = REPLACE(name, 'ú', 'u');
```

Comment: Maybe you could write a multi-replace function in sql.

Comment: You may want to look into user defined regex replace functions in mysql. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755408/mysql-regex-replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the replace calls, so it can be done in a single query:

```
UPDATE person SET name = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(name, 'á', 'a'), 'é', 'e'), 'í', 'i')
```

But this quickly becomes an unmaintainable mess. If you're simply trying to replace accented characters with their unaccented equivalents, maybe a character set change would be of more use.

Answer (score 0):

Replace like this you all are talking about become mess if u want to replace all alphabets.
You can make one table with two colums such as 1st column consist 'á' and second 'a' similarly for whole.
and then make a procedure to fetch each row of new table and then done the replace.