# Query to modify a record the same way for all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

There are roughly 4000 file paths stored in the img_path column in a table called 'sunshine'.

The structure to all of these paths changed the same way.

I was wondering if it is possible to run a mySQL query that will change all current image path records, to the newly changed one, for all records in the 'sunshine' table?

Note: the only difference between the old and new path is that I need to add a sunny directory to all previous img_paths.

Current 'img_path' column:

```
images/a/a1.jpg 
images/a/a2.jpg 
images/a/a3.jpg
```

What I am trying to accomplish:

```
images/sunny/a/a1.jpg
images/sunny/a/a2.jpg
images/sunny/a/a3.jpg
```

many thanks in advance!

Comment: How about you show us your table schema (`SHOW CREATE sunshine`) and we can help you create a query to update the table?

Comment: see, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755408/mysql-regex-replace - you're looking for REGEXP_REPLACE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE Sunshine
SET img_paths = REPLACE(img_paths,'images/','images/sunny/');
```