# Delete / replace all images in a SQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, html-parsing

I have a mysql database with 400k posts. In arround 100k posts are images. Example:

```
text text text <img src="/images/test.jpg"> text text text
```

The complete image string `<img src="/images/test.jpg">` must be deleted. But its not always `<img src/images/test.jpg">` there are many variants. So I could not use the typical sql replace .

What I need is "sql replace between two characters". For me, delete / replace everything  between `"<img" and ">"`  and off course incloude the `<img and >`

Is that anyways possible?
Thank you

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: The database part is not the important part.  What you're really talking about is parsing HTML.  Look at http://htmlparsing.com/ for ideas.  You're not going to be able to do this only with SQL.

Comment: thank you so much for your quick reply.

100k entries are a lot. I need to remove this images complete out of the database. I know I could replace them with php before they are displaying but for me it would be better to delete the images direct in the database. 

I tried it with something like this

stackoverflow.com/questions/8850798/sql-replace-all-characters-between-two-strings

but without success.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Added the regex tag to broaden the audience.  I believe the answer lies there.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are those pictures in the database? Do you just wanna remove the tag from HTML or you want to remove the pictures too? What do you need to do with the database?

Comment: do you have a example? I am not good with regex and i am a dummy with sql :/

Comment: Hi Texas bruce,

the image path is in the database and i want remove the complete image path from the database. thank you in advance

Comment: @DanBracuk, as [has been definitively answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), this is most definitely ***not*** a regex problem.

Comment: Please show us your table structure (are `text`s separate fields?), some examples of the existing tag variations, and the final result you expect in the database. Is the `<img>` tag embedded inside XML or HTML? Also, what's the purpose of an empty `<img>` tag if it's _always_ going to be empty? Why not just remove it completely?

Comment: Hi Branko, thank you. Here is thestructure: 

DB: phpbb
Table: phpbb_posts
Field: post_text

It´s a old database from 2002. From 2002 - 2007 the phpbb forum had html allowed. Many people placed images over html in the forum. Like I said arround 100 000. I tested it with %<img%. 

I have to delete every image path in the database, because there is no need for. It only fills up the DB and looks ugly in posts, when there is only the image path. I know I can enable html again but this I dont want. 

example

Hello, &lt;img src="images/smiley_icons/icon_smile.gif" border=0 alt="Smile"&gt; how

Comment: NO <img> is not embedded anymore because html is disabled. For me all html that begins with <img and end with > could be deleted. Yes, I want remove it completly out of the database. Again: every path that looks like <img src="......."> could be deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Regex Replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755408/mysql-regex-replace)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports regex:

```
UPDATE Mytable SET url = '' WHERE url RLIKE someregex;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Something like:

```
UPDATE Mytable SET url = '' WHERE url RLIKE '\\<img.\\>'
```

**But note** that MySQL does not support output of regex mangled strings. It will only compare.

However, there is a MySQL user function REGEX_REPLACE, see: https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp
See also this question: [How to count words in MySQL / regular expression replacer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755408/mysql-regex-replace)