# Regular expression to replace broken email links

Tags: php, regex

Problem: authors have added email addresses wrongly in a CMS - missing out the 'mailto:' text.

**I need a regular expression, if possible, to do a search and replace on the stored MySQL content table.**

Cases I need to cope with are:

1. No 'mailto:'
2. 'mailto:' is already included (correct)
3. web address not email - no replace
4. multiple mailto: required (more than one in string)

Sample string would be: (line breaks added for readability)

```
<a href="add1@test.com">add1@test.com</a> and
<a href="mailto:add2@test.com">add2@test.com</a> and
<a href="http://www.test.com/">real web link</a>
second one to replace <a href="add3@test.com">add3@test.com</a>
```

Required output would be:

```
<a href="mailto:add1@test.com">add1@test.com</a> and
<a href="mailto:add2@test.com">add2@test.com</a> and
<a href="http://www.test.com/">real web link</a>
second one to replace <a href="mailto:add3@test.com">add3@test.com</a>
```

What I tried (in PHP) and issues:

```
pattern:   /href="(.+?)(@)(.+?)(<\/a> )/iU
replacement:    href="mailto:$1$2$3$4
```

This is adding mailto: to the correctly formatted mailto: and acting greedily over the last two links.

Thanks for any help. I have looked about, but am running out of time on this as it was an unexpected content issue.

If you are able to save me time and give the SQL expression, that would be even better.

Comment: MySQL does not have REGEXP replace built in. There are user-defined functions, but it looks like a dump followed by off-line processing is the best option - see:

[Stack Overflow discussion how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace

```
/href="(?!(mailto:|http:\/\/|www\.))/iU
```

with

```
href="mailto:
```

`?!` loosely means "the next characters aren't these".

**Alternative:**

Replace

```
/(href=")(?!mailto:)([^"]+@)/iU
```

with

```
$1mailto:$2
```

`[^"]+` means 1 or more characters that aren't `"`.

You'd probably need a more complex matching pattern for guaranteed correctness.

**MySQL REGEX matching:**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1755627/1711796) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql).

Comment: First one works OK in PHP but needs escaping:

`/href="(?!(mailto:|http:\/\/|www\.))/iU';`

Comment: Second one gives duplicate where the mailto already exists:
`mailto:mailto:`

Many thanks for this - I'll try first in SQL

Comment: As stated above MySQL does not have REGEXP replace built in, but this was the code I used off-line in an SQL dump file. Thanks @Dukeling also for the pointers to MySQL. Overall problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a proper mail pattern first (e.g: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)), second search for  `mailto:`before mail or nothing (e.g: `(mailto:|)`), and last `preg_replace_callback` suits for this.

This looks like working as you wish (searching only email addresses in double quotes);

```
$s = '<a href="add1@test.com">add1@test.com</a> and 
<a href="mailto:add2@test.com">add2@test.com</a> and 
<a href="http://www.test.com/">real web link</a> 
second one to replace <a href="add3@test.com">add3@test.com</a>';
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~"(mailto:|)([_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4}))"~i', 
    function($m) {
        // print_r($m); @debug
        return '"mailto:'. $m[2] .'"';
    },
    $s
);
```

Output as you desired;

```
<a href="mailto:add1@test.com">add1@test.com</a> and 
<a href="mailto:add2@test.com">add2@test.com</a> and 
<a href="http://www.test.com/">real web link</a> 
second one to replace <a href="mailto:add3@test.com">add3@test.com</a>
```

Comment: Many thanks. This worked on my test except I have PHP 5.2 so I had to use a normal function:

`
function cbfunc($m) {
 return '"mailto:'. $m[2] .'"';
}
 
$newstr = preg_replace_callback(
 '~"(mailto:|)([_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4}))"~i', 
 cbfunc,
 $s
 );
`
However I needed SQL, so preg_replace_callback() not available.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following as pattern:

```
/(href=")(?!mailto:)(.+?@.+?")/iU
```

and replace it with

```
$1mailto:$2
```

`(?!mailto:)` is a negative lookahead checking whether a `mailto:` follows. If there is no such one, remaining part is checked for matching. `(.+?@.+?")` matches one or more characters followed by a `@` followed by one or more characters followed by a `"`. Both `+` are non-greedy.

The matched pattern is replaced with first capture group (`href="`) followed by `mailto:` followed by second capture group (upto closing `"`).

Comment: Thanks for this. 
It does not seem to work on the second email link that does not have mailto:

Comment: @mjpg in which case it is not working? it seems to be working for your example as far as i tested.

Comment: For my install, it is not replacing
`href="add3@test.com"`

Comment: @mjpg try `(href=")(?!mailto:)(.+?@.+?")` alone, without the modifiers. It's working for me

Comment: @mjpg do you have multiline enabled?