# Adding zeros to specific place in mySQL table row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL table with alot of links like this:

```
id - link
1 | index.php?video=12
2 | index.php?video=345
3 | index.php?video=6789
4 | index.php?video=123&other=variable
5 | www.site.com/index.php?video=456&other=variable
```

One link per text row. I would like to add zeros before the numbers but it has to be nine numbers in total. so video=12 would be video=000000012 and video=6789 would be video=000006789.

Is there some way to acheive this by using SQL query?

EDIT: the solution tombom submitted worked fine but what if I have links that don't have the video=x variable?

Comment: look at regex replace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755408/mysql-regex-replace

Comment: Have a look at [MySQL regex-replace](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp)

Comment: it would be a better idea to only store the ID number (12 etc) and then generate the link when you are outputting it. You could then format this pretty easy in any programming language you use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET `link` = REPLACE(`link`, SUBSTRING(`link` from LOCATE('=', `link`) + 1), RIGHT(CONCAT('000000000', SUBSTRING(`link` from LOCATE('=', `link`) + 1)), 9))
```

See it working live [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8f66/2/0) in an sqlfiddle.

**UPDATE:**

> What if I have some links with more url variables? like: index.php?video=123&play=1&search=hello

That's a bit trickier, but here you go:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET `link` = replace(`link`, substring(`link`, locate('=', `link`) + 1, ABS(locate('&', `link`) - locate('=', `link`) - 1)), right(concat('000000000', substring(`link`, locate('=', `link`) + 1, ABS(locate('&', `link`) - locate('=', `link`) - 1))), 9))
```

Or you can do it a bit shorter like this:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET `link` = , CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`link`, '=', 1),'=', LPAD(SUBSTRING(`link` from locate('=', `link`) + 1),9,'0'))
```

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f084d/12/0).

Comment: What if I have some links with more url variables? like: index.php?video=123&play=1&search=hello

Comment: That worked but I found I hade some links in there that don't have the video=x variable at all. Those links got screw up. How do I not apply the query to them?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1 SET `link` = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`link`, '=', 1),'=', LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`link`, '=', -1),9,'0'))
```

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8f66/10/0)

Comment: What if I have some links with more url variables? like: index.php?video=123&play=1&search=hello