# Regex search and replace on all rows in a table with Laravel 4's Fluent or Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, regex, laravel, laravel-4

What's the best way to use Fluent or Eloquent to search for a pattern in a MySQL database and replace it?

I've seen [in the Laravel forums](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=8071) that you *should* be able to do a regex selection like so

```
// Searching for the word "mypattern"...
Page::where('words', 'regexp', DB::raw('/\bmypattern\b/'))->get();
```

But I've tried this method and it doesn't seem to select the rows I'm after. In any case, actually don't want to JUST select--**I'd like to actually do a search and replace with regex**.

What's the best way to do this with the options provided by Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that 'regexp' is a [valid query operator](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Query.Builder.html#137) in Laravel 4.

It seems that Taylor has actually made a comment specific to this issue on Github under [issue #838](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/838), and he suggests using whereRaw instead of where.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755408/mysql-regex-replace) is an SO question regarding MySQL Regex Replace, which may help you to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use a MySQL `User Defined Function` (UDF) for what you're asking. **Note** that using a `UDF` is not always compatible but might be good enough to do for your case.

The UDF package mod will implement your regular expression as a User Defined Function and is supported by the regular expression `REGEXP` operator.

See [MySQL regular expression functions](http://udf-regexp.sourceforge.net/)

Another option would be to dump your data and do a find and replace.