# Querying eloquent model with the range of alphabets

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am trying to select the users who are listed in the given range of their first name initials.

For example, if the name of the person starts with letter `C` then the user will select the range, lets say, `A-E`. So for that, he will click on range `A-E` and that range will display all the users whose name starts with either `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`.

In order to do that I am trying to query the laravel eloquent, but I cannot find the desired solution. On bit of research, I found [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/263378/SQL-Query-To-select-Employee-name-Start-with-A-to) that provides the solution, but it didn't provided me what I am looking for.

The query that I did is:

```
public function getAllUsers(Request $request)
{
    $users = User::where('account_type', 'beneficiary')->latest()->get();

    if($request->range !== null) {
        $users = User::where('account_type', 'beneficiary')->where('full_name', "REGEXP '^".$request->range.".*$'")->latest()->get();

        dd($users); // returned an empty Collection object
    }

    return view('pages.beneficiaries', compact('users'));
}
```

**Bottom Line:** Fetch the users whose name starts within the given range that the user will select.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

**P.S**: I know this might be quite simple to solve, but I am failing in it.

**UPDATE 1: Solution**

With the help of @Armen, I was able to solve the issue. The query that I passed to the eloquent model is the following:

```
// Notice the curly braces and also the removal of single quotes
$users = User::where('account_type', 'beneficiary')
         ->where('full_name', 'REGEXP', "^[{$request->range}].*$") 
         ->get();
```

Comment: What is in your `$request->range` variable ? have you dumped it ?

Comment: it is `a-e`, for the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your found example (mentioned in issue description) value of REGEXP should be in scopes [] like this `'^[A-E].*$'` so change your second where to `where('full_name', "REGEXP '^[".$request->range."].*$'")` and also take into account Upper and Lowercase letter`a-e` is not same as `A-E`

**UPDATE**

as we founded out with @user3514160 the `where` condition should look like this

```
->where('full_name', 'REGEXP', "^[{$request->range}].*$")
```

Comment: Nope, didn't worked.. returned an empty `Collection` object

Comment: Try to call DB::table('table') ..... ->toSql() to see the real sql query which you execute

Comment: Here's the output of `DB::table('users')`: `"select * from users where account_type = ? and full_name = ?"`

Comment: ok seems i got your problem change your where to this `where('full_name',  'REGEXP',  "'^[".$request->range."].*$'")`, also make sure if this query `select * from users where account_type = 'beneficiary' and full_name REGEXP '^[A-E].*$'` give you something in phpmyadmin

Comment: you got it in phpmyadmin or at php side ? is matches amount correct ?

Comment: If I execute the `select * from users where account_type = 'beneficiary' and full_name REGEXP '^[A-E].*$'` in phpmyadmin, I got 3 results but here in laravel DB, returns an empty `[]`

Comment: ok seems where did not support REGEXP in laravel (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884333/regex-search-and-replace-on-all-rows-in-a-table-with-laravel-4s-fluent-or-eloqu) use instead `whereRow` like this `whereRaw("account_type = 'beneficiary' and full_name REGEXP '^[A-E].*$'")`

Comment: No issues sir.. I have solved it. Here's what I did: `User::where('account_type', 'beneficiary')->where('full_name', 'REGEXP', "^[{$request->range}].*$")->get();` and it gave me the desired result.